# Outlook Search Folder Criteria

Tags: vba, outlook

Is it possible to set criteria of a Search Folder in Outlook to a large number of keywords, like this:

```
subject contains "abc" OR "def" OR "ghi" ...
```

**Search for the word(s)** box in **Search Folder Criteria** does support comma-separated list of values, but the max. length of that box is quite limited (255 chars I guess). The number of keywords I have is very large (hundreds of them). Adding them manually through **Advanced** tab is also a pain, so I'm looking for a more programmer's way. One of the following should work:

1. If Outlook stores these criteria in a flat file somewhere (like Thunderbird does), I'll edit it directly and inject my keywords into it.
2. If I could manipulate the criteria through Object Model (VBA), that's also a good solution.
3. If VSTO can do it, I have that experience as well.

Does someone know if any of the above method works?

Note: I'm using Outlook 2013 if that has something to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop either a VBA macro or an Outlook add-in (VSTO can be used for developing an add-in). Try using the [AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866933.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the Application class. See [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for more information.